# Deployment of Next.js app with Flask as backend

Tags: flask, next.js

For the first time I am trying to deploy nextjs app with flask as backend.

I used flask in my pages/api directory.

If I run "npm run build" It will just be running "info Creating an optimized production build" for a while and nothing happens.

The script code in pacakge.json:

```
"scripts": {
"flask-dev": "python -m flask --app pages/api/index run -p 8080 --reload",
"next-dev": "next dev",
"dev": "concurrently \"pnpm run next-dev\" \"pnpm run flask-dev\"",
"build": "next build"
},
```

I am not sure if python will be running if I just build next js app, but since I havent deployed any app like this I appreciate any anwer and help.

My question is:
Will python be running on my hosted web site if I just persist and wait for the npm build to be finished?

Comment: I found this external link to be helpful. IDK if it answers your question however.  https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-next-js-flask/